# SharePoint 2013 how to disable crawling document content

Tags: 2013, search, document, crawling, content

SharePoint 2013 foundation How to disable crawling document content. The search result is returning way to much information for my users. Need to crawl only metadata (columns) and file name.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall Microsoft Filter Pack from your server and reset the search index after that? Source & information here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1de8cf95-b3e3-4e40-a9d1-605339f02cca/prevent-sharepoint-crawler-from-crawling-content-of-the-documents?forum=sharepointsearchprevious and here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621079(v=office.14).aspx I hope you get something out of this! :)

Comment: Yes this is helpful for SharePoint 2010 but the Search works differently in SharePoint 2013. In 2013 you navigate to Central Administration, Manage service applications, Search Service Application, on the left under Queries and Results you click Search Schema. I just can't seem to get the right combination to accomplish what my users need.

Comment: Ok I see, sorry that the link did not help you! I'll let you know if I find anything useful regarding this matter. :-)

Comment: Couldn't you just modify the search results page to only search on the title field?

Answer (score 1):

1. Crawl Rule https://eDocs/sites/FsOperation/*.doc, *.docx etc Exclude these path. Need to verify this as it is based on file extension
2. Remove allowed file types from Search Service Application – GLOBAL IMPACT ACROSS complete Search Services Application
3. Remove column which contains document text from crawled property list / managed property list – GLOBAL IMPACT ACROSS complete Search Services Application

Please suggest if anyone has another approach.

Thanks